# PHP SQLite Extensions not loading

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm trying to load an extension on my PHP site:

```
$db->loadExtension('libdbplusql_81203.so');
```

PHP.ini:

```
sqlite3.extension_dir = /usr/lib/php/20180731
```

Error-Log from Apache2:

```
PHP Warning:  SQLite3::loadExtension(): /usr/lib/php/20180731/libdbplusql_81203.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in /var/www/pdb/index.php on line 76
```

Can't figure out why this is not working.... and it's weird, that in the error log it says ".so.so" - when I change my code to:

```
$db->loadExtension('libdbplusql_81203');
```

Error Log say:

```
PHP Warning:  SQLite3::loadExtension(): Unable to load extension at '/usr/lib/php/20180731/libdbplusql_81203' in /var/www/pdb/index.php on line 76
```

Maybe you have an idea :-)

Comment: Does your PHP process have proper read permissions to this folder?

Comment: Does the file `libdbplusql_81203.so` exists on the directory `/usr/lib/php/20180731`?

Comment: rights are set to 777 for testing, yes the .so file is in this directory.

Comment: What happens if you used `file_get_contents`? Maybe this is related to `open_basedir`?

Comment: open_basedir is not active. file_get_contents is working on that file. I can print_r(file_get_contents('/usr/lib/php/20180731/libdbplusql_81203.so')); correct